# Looking for a mailman equivalent which uses a MySQL backend

Tags: php, mysql, mailing-list, mailman

I have been running a mailing list using Mailman which is installed on my server, so that anyone on the mailing list can send an email to a single email address and it gets sent out to everyone on the list.  I would now like to find a way of doing something similar using a MySQL table to store the users in, as I want people to be able to sign up to the Mailing List through a form on a website, and I would also like to use the MySQL database for other purposes.

Could someone suggest any such alternatives to Mailman?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

What might be an alternative - especially if your web programming environment is python-based - is to hook into mailman from Python. Inspect the `withlist` script that comes with mailman for inspiration on how to get hold of a list object where you can read existing members and add new ones from your web app.

I see now you've tagged the post with php, so this is probably not an option. Still, consider calling the existing scripts such as `add_members` from your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Mailman 3 is in development and will offer this feature.  They just came out with the first beta version.